# Next js 13 using own api for nodemailer

Tags: http, next.js, get, nodemailer, next.js13

I'm building a app that needs a email system, I build it before in pages/api/email that worked.

because of it getting bigger by the day, I want to build a api for the email on app/api/email.

I keep getting a error:

`- error No HTTP methods exported in 'C:\Users\Nodefion\Desktop\Workspace\_Git_REPOS\test\app\api\mail\route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.`

Main page
app(group)\email\page.jsx

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function HomePage() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

  const sendEmail = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/mail', { method: 'GET' });
      const data = await res.json();
      setResponse(data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to My App</h1>
      <p>Click the button to send an email:</p>
      <button onClick={sendEmail}>Send Email</button>
      {response && <p>{response}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

app\api\mail\route.js

```
import { nodemailer } from 'nodemailer';
export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const smtpConfig = {
      host: 'smtp.hostinger.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: 'noreply@mail.com',
        pass: 'password',
      },
    };

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);


    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'noreply@mail.com',
      to: 'mail@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Test Email',
      text: 'This is a test email sent from nodemailer.', 
    };

    try {

      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email sent successfully!' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error sending email' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).end(); // Method Not Allowed for non-GET requests
  }
};
```

I change the credentials for security reasons so I tried this on /page/api/email with different code and that worked.

I'm still new to Next.js but some how im getting confused and keeps bupping up in the error.

I have looked over the internet but there always using the thing I dont want and thats pages/api/email.

Thanks for having a look & have a blessed day.

I tried looking on different forums used ai for this and still keep comming up empty handed.

Answer (score 3):

The route handlers get some updates in the app router. [See the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)

To create a route handler export `named` function with the API method like:

```js
export async function GET(req, context) {}
export async function POST(req, context) {}
export async function PATCH(req, context) {}
export async function PUT(req, context) {}
export async function DELETE(req, context) {}
export async function OPTIONS(req, context) {}
```

Comment: I tried that one too like ! 

`import { nodemailer } from 'nodemailer';

export async function POST(request) {

}
`

Comment: what's wrong with that? Notice that you are exporting `POST` but fetching `GET`